# I get assigned technically impossible tasks

Tags: communication, new-job

I've started in a new company a few months ago, I had to move and I did not do my research. In my old company I had my team, a git, we had design patterns and everything was smooth. At my new position I am the only person and there was nothing, everything was done by a extern and now he is just overwhelmed by his tasks, he refuses to share any source code. It's a nuclear meltdown with the extern, everyone gave up, lawyers and alot of money.

No one in this at my current workplace has the slightest idea of software development. The first idea of my boss was that I will replace everything the extern has done in the last ~10 years. I said with his source code it could be done within a much shorter timeframe. Since this is not a option anymore, we decided to start from scratch and I estimated that I need 65 weeks to implement the basic functions of project #1. It is a STM32 and I would use C, it's a complete industrial device and I am alone, my estimation was even pretty low. Well, everyone is shocked by this estimation.

Project #2: after not even 2 weeks there is another project, generate ~800 protocols from CSV data, no problem. I've wrote a little script and everything works fine. Except that older data is broken, some data does not even exist. I told my boss about it but he simply said I should figure something out. I really don't know what there can be done if the data does not exist, I mean...

Project #3: I am working on Project #2 and I am halfway done to a point where I can't continue because of known reasons. There is this folder where people did "version control", by copying the old file and renaming it. After many years of renaming files without any convention I have to automatically sort out any old file (previous version). It's really impossible, I don't know anything about this software they use, so I can't suggest what version control makes sense.

Everything I do fails or I have to tell someone that I can't do it. Seems like I am not capable. I am not sure what the solution for this is. What I see:

1. I will be fired at some point because it seems like it's my fault
2. I stay here for some years and my skills probaly get crippled because everything is rushed and just frustrating
3. Everything will be fine ? I don't see how

Edit1: clarify my question

Is there anything I can do to improve my situation. How can I explain to someone that something is not possible to do. Financially this job is interesting, I could even sit it out until I am fired. Is this a valid option ?

Comment: Sounds like a bad situation that you're in, but I'm not sure there is a question buried in there. Can you clarify?

Comment: Is the external contractor still in the picture? Or have they been terminated?

Comment: @numenor They are "still in the picture". But everyone thinks it's their fault (it's not) and there is ongoing legal proceedings to get the source code

Comment: Keep telling the boss how the world looks.  Be completely frank even if he did not ask for it.  That makes it the organizations decision of what to do, rather than you hiding information from those who decide.  It may even be influential on what happens afterwards.

Comment: Document everything. Make another script that raport only data missing. Like "data missing in field X" or "Request Xa345: no data in repository". At each week send the list to your boss that he should pass that to whoever is responsible for that data.

Comment: Your 65 week estimate for the STM32 project is not credible, because there is simply *no way* that you will not discover things and have changes in the requirement during that time frame which completely throw off the basis of the estimation.  You are definitely in a challenging situation, but to succeed there you are going to have to start breaking down projects into *approachable pieces* rather than seeing an unconquerable mountain.

Answer (score 14):

It’s a challenging situation but not impossible. You have to replace ten years of work, that’s not going to come for free. Your company will eventually figure out that this is a hard job. If you don’t deliver what they hope for (you won’t) you need to make sure that they know that replacing you isn’t going to help.

It seems on top of all of it your priorities are being changed. The first thing to do is making sure that management knows this *will* delay everything else.

For your work: First, set up source code control. Make sure that the source code is on some server, and on your machine. Set up automatic backup. Make sure you have an efficient machine so you are the only limiting factor. Two large monitors. You are there for the long haul. And if you are replaced, you don’t want your successor to start with the same mess.

As far as your work is concerned: Don’t rush. *Never* rush. It only takes longer. Do not let anyone stress you. Whatever problem, it’s your manager’s problem, not yours. Every day, start work, figure out what you want to do this day, try to do it, and eight hours later you go home.

Answer (score 5):

> No one in this at my current workplace has the slightest idea of software development. The first idea of my boss was that I will replace everything the extern has done in the last ~10 years. I said with his source code it could be done within a much shorter timeframe. Since this is not a option anymore, we decided to start from scratch and I estimated that I need 65 weeks to implement the basic functions of project #1. It is a STM32 and I would use C, it's a complete industrial device and I am alone, my estimation was even pretty low. Well, everyone is shocked by this estimation.

Since your boss has no idea how software development works, explain to him in simple terms: "You're asking me to replace 10 years of someone's work.  I'm telling you I can do it in a year and a half (less actually).  That's an 8x improvement.  I can't do better than 8x improvement".  That's really all there is to it.  You don't need to be a rocket scientist (or in this case computer scientist) to understand that people can only work so fast and you can't just snap your fingers and make an application out of thin air.

As an aside: It would probably be worse if you had the original source code.  If management is so bad at understanding software, the old guy probably took a bunch of shortcuts he shouldn't have taken, and reading his source code would probably just confuse you even more.  Ask for requirements from project management (there's gotta be someone who knows what this application does, at least at a high level) and rebuild it from there.

> Project #2: after not even 2 weeks there is another project, generate ~800 protocols from CSV data, no problem. I've wrote a little script and everything works fine. Except that older data is broken, some data does not even exist. I told my boss about it but he simply said I should figure something out. I really don't know what there can be done if the data does not exist, I mean...

Someone needs to tell you what you should expect to happen if the data is not there.  Verify, again, with project management, if your boss is no help.  Explain the data is bad and you want to know how to handle the data.  They might not understand, so explain what the problem is as simply as you can: "Some data is missing and I don't know what to do.  Do you want this to be logged somehow?  Should there be some kind of default method for missing data?  Should I just ignore it?"  Missing data is not necessarily a problem, but missing specifications are.

Aside: What happened to your 65 week estimate for project #1?  Did you cave?  Does your boss understand that by piling you up with project #2, then progress on project #1 will be delayed?

> Project #3: I am working on Project #2 and I am halfway done to a point where I can't continue because of known reasons. There is this folder where people did "version control", by copying the old file and renaming it. After many years of renaming files without any convention I have to automatically sort out any old file (previous version). It's really impossible, I don't know anything about this software they use, so I can't suggest what version control makes sense.

I once had a similar problem at a company I worked for.  It wasn't quite this bad; we had the old source code, but the source was written really badly and nobody really knew what anything did.  We could have spent some time analyzing the source and replicating the functionality, but that would have been very time consuming.  So instead, we redesigned the product from the ground up.  We threw out the old source, just tossed it in the trash, and re-specced all the features and rebuilt everything from the ground up.  This might be what you want to do as well.  Forget about those old source files and the old "version control".  It will take you too long to figure it out.  Instead, ask for specifications.  If this application is important enough, *someone* must have some idea what it does, at least at a high level.  Find that person and talk to them and get specifications for it.  Then throw the old code in the trash and rebuild it from those specifications.  If nobody knows what the application was supposed to do, then probably they didn't need/use it and you can refocus on other things.

Aside: You should explain GitHub to your company, what it's for, what it does, and why they should buy you an account to use.  Especially in light of the legal fight they're having with the previous guy, you can explain it in those terms: "If you put all your code in this repository, then you own all the code and you have access to it always; it's not sitting on some random guy's computer and you have to fight with him to get it".  Just say that and see how it goes.

Answer (score 4):

This isn't an uncommon situation when taking over from someone, especially an external contractor who will have done the absolute bare minimum to fulfil their obligations. So no need to panic.

Start by documenting all the problems and making sure your boss has a copy. Email it over. If something turns out to be more complex than you first thought then just say so. You found some issue you hadn't seen in the limited time you had to make an estimate, and be sure to detail what the issue is. Again, make sure it is in writing.

In future remember to take the time you think something will take and at least double it. You know what they have is low quality and full of problems so tripling might not be a bad idea, and feel free to hedge your estimates a bit by stating your assumptions or asking for more time to investigate.

If a job is simply impossible then say so. Tell them that they need to get certain information about versions from the external or you can't do it. Offer them an alternative, say you try to sort it out (which will take a long time) and maintain a proper version history from now on, discarding the old stuff.

The best solution in these cases is always brutal honesty. It's not your fault, the other person did a bad job and you will of course do your best to sort it out.

Answer (score -1):

What I can recommend is:

1. One night in your free time study how to set up a peronal/private git server (surely there are sites that offer the service to different tiers). Prepare a nice document where you explain the importance of having it, what benefits it will bring, and that those who will have to use it can do a small course of a few hours to understand how it works.
2. Talk to your boss, show the document for the software versioning and organize a meeting with all the groups that generate the data, find a common factor on format and shipping mode and put it all in black and white in a beautiful functional analysis document that will be the bible for years to come.

What you're asking your boss is to be what he should be, a guide and a point of reference, if every office does what it wants this is just a hindrance and a waste of time for everyone.

Comment: It is part of your job read up on git in work timr

Comment: I disagree, where I work we are very compartmentalized, but developers do not have to deal with the infrastructure, but the system admins or whoever manages the company's servers. What he should try to do would be to make the decision-makers realize that more organization is needed, he can READ about git but not do the actual work alone or at least with the same pay.